# Ruby max integer

Tags: ruby, fixnum

I need to be able to determine a systems maximum integer in Ruby. Anybody know how, or if it's possible?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ruby automatically converts integers to a large integer class when they overflow, so there's (practically) no limit to how big they can be.

If you are looking for the machine's size, i.e. 64- or 32-bit, I found [this trick at ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/177435):

```
machine_bytes = ['foo'].pack('p').size
machine_bits = machine_bytes * 8
machine_max_signed = 2**(machine_bits-1) - 1
machine_max_unsigned = 2**machine_bits - 1
```

---

If you are looking for the size of Fixnum objects (integers small enough to store in a single machine word), you can call `0.size` to get the number of bytes. I would guess it should be 4 on 32-bit builds, but I can't test that right now. Also, the largest Fixnum is apparently `2**30 - 1` (or `2**62 - 1`), because one bit is used to mark it as an integer instead of an object reference.

Comment: Pretty sure you want 2**(machine_size * 8) -1; 2**4-1=15 which is not a very large anything.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I started thinking too much about bytes instead of bits.

Comment: WARNING: The code is useless.  Read the edit, ignore the code.  It doesn't find the maximum anything for Ruby.  It finds it for code that does not use tagged pointers.

Comment: now (2018-01-21) it's 32bits even in 64bit ruby on windows (cygwin has proper 64bit on other hand)

Answer (score 84):

```
FIXNUM_MAX = (2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1)
FIXNUM_MIN = -(2**(0.size * 8 -2))
```

Comment: Why did you subtract 2 bits instead of 1 for the sign? I tested this and it seems to be correct, but why does Ruby use 2 bits for the sign?

Comment: @Matthias An extra bit is used to mark the value as an integer (as opposed to a pointer to an object).

Comment: This is not true for JRuby, at least. In JRuby, `Fixnum` is always 64 Bit (not 63 or 31 bit like in YARV) regardless of machine word size, and there is no tag bit.

Comment: @Matthias [Old question, maybe you have the answer now, but...] signed integers in almost every language use "Two's Compliment" representation.  The range is -2**(n-1) up to 2**(n-1)-1 because the interpretation of the bits accounts for the sign, which uses a bit.  (The positive maxvalue is smaller than the negative abs(minvalue), because one of its bit patterns represents 0, so it "gives up" a value the negative range doesn't.)  If a Ruby implementations uses tagged ints, it only uses _one_ extra bit for tracking whether the value fits in a register or if it needs an allocated object.

Answer (score 13):

Reading the friendly manual? Who'd want to do that?

```
start = Time.now
largest_known_fixnum = 1
smallest_known_bignum = nil

until smallest_known_bignum == largest_known_fixnum + 1
  if smallest_known_bignum.nil?
    next_number_to_try = largest_known_fixnum * 1000
  else
    next_number_to_try = (smallest_known_bignum + largest_known_fixnum) / 2 # Geometric mean would be more efficient, but more risky
  end

  if next_number_to_try <= largest_known_fixnum ||
       smallest_known_bignum && next_number_to_try >= smallest_known_bignum
    raise "Can't happen case" 
  end

  case next_number_to_try
    when Bignum then smallest_known_bignum = next_number_to_try
    when Fixnum then largest_known_fixnum = next_number_to_try
    else raise "Can't happen case"
  end
end

finish = Time.now
puts "The largest fixnum is #{largest_known_fixnum}"
puts "The smallest bignum is #{smallest_known_bignum}"
puts "Calculation took #{finish - start} seconds"
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that returns numbers at the transition from Fixnum to Bignum, which, to me, means that is the largest Fixnum in Ruby.

Answer (score 11):

In ruby Fixnums are automatically converted to Bignums.

To find the highest possible Fixnum you could do something like this:

```
class Fixnum
 N_BYTES = [42].pack('i').size
 N_BITS = N_BYTES * 8
 MAX = 2 ** (N_BITS - 2) - 1
 MIN = -MAX - 1
end
p(Fixnum::MAX)
```

Shamelessly ripped from a [ruby-talk discussion](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/149748).  Look there for more details.

Comment: If you do `puts (Fixnum::MAX + 1).class` this doesn't return `Bignum` like it seems like it should. If you change `8` to `16` it will.

Answer (score 4):

There is no maximum since Ruby 2.4, as Bignum and Fixnum got unified into Integer. see [Feature #12005](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12005)

```rb
> (2 << 1000).is_a? Fixnum
(irb):322: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
=> true

> 1.is_a? Bignum
(irb):314: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> true

> (2 << 1000).class
=> Integer
```

There won't be any overflow, what would happen is an out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

as @Jörg W Mittag pointed out: in jruby, fix num size is always 8 bytes long. This code snippet shows the truth:

```
fmax = ->{
  if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
    2**63 - 1
  else
    2**(0.size * 8 - 2) - 1
  end
}.call

p fmax.class     # Fixnum

fmax = fmax + 1  

p fmax.class     #Bignum
```