# Why are Ruby Fixnums missing one bit?

Tags: ruby, fixnum

Ruby [Fixnums](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html) are 64-bit on 64-bit rubies:

```
bits = 8 * 0.size 
# => 64
```

The maximum signed integer under [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is `9_223_372_036_854_775_807`, but the maximum Fixnum in Ruby is only half that:

```
[(1 << 62) - 1,  1 << 62].map(&:class)
# => [Fixnum, Bignum]
max = (1 << 62) - 1 
# => 4611686018427387903
max.to_s 2
# => "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" (62 bits)
```

How does Ruby use the missing bit? MRI [Fixnum doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html) only mentions it briefly:

> [Fixnum] Holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). 
>   If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum.

Tested with: [MRI 2.1.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), [JRuby 1.7.13](http://jruby.org/), and [Rubinius 2.2.10](http://rubini.us/).

Comment: Not a duplicate, but your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535721/ruby-max-integer  Short version is that one bit is used to mark it as an int.

Comment: Thanks, found it: `one bit is used to mark it as an integer instead of an object reference`. More detail would be interesting.

Comment: Have you read the C source to see how `Fixnum`s work at the lower levels? The `fix_*` functions in `numeric.c` might be enlightening.

Comment: The chapter on extending Ruby in the Pickaxe book (which is available online) explains this quite well. See section 2.2, _Ruby Objects in C_ :http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf

Comment: @matt Section 2.2 answers the question perfectly. If you answer with a quote  from there I will accept. Many thanks.

Comment: Your code will output `[Integer, Integer]` as of Ruby 2.4.0.