# A loop with many iterations makes execution incredibly slow

Tags: ruby, loops, execution-time

Execution time for this code is around 1 second:

```
start_time = Time.now

prev = 1
(1..1000).each do |i|
  (1..10000).each do |j|
    result = j * prev
    result = result + prev
    result = result - prev
    result = result / prev
    prev = j
  end
end

end_time = Time.now
printf('%f sec', end_time - start_time)
```

But when I use one loop with 10000000 iterations (instead of 2 loops, 1000 and 10000 iterations as written above), it becames much slower (around 4.5 seconds):

```
start_time = Time.now

prev = 1
(1..10000000).each do |j|
  result = j * prev
  result = result + prev
  result = result - prev
  result = result / prev
  prev = j
end

end_time = Time.now
printf('%f sec', end_time - start_time)
```

Why is it happening? The total iterations number is still the same.

Comment: Try to investigate values of `result` in each case. I think `10_000_000 * 9_999_999` is greater than `10_000 * 9_999`.

Comment: I have 1.35sec for the first, and 1.24sec for the second code. The variable `result` do not grow excessively, because it is resetted each time.

Comment: So basically, iteration of the first code is 1.35 seconds and 1.24 seconds for the second? Odd.
Try logging execution at smaller chunks, every 20% of the total for instance. The overall load should increase equally with a simple check, so it shouldn't visibly affect the test.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: The first is `1.288465 sec`, the second `1.219005 sec` on my computer. What do you try to achieve with this examples?

Comment: @spickermann I just run these scripts in the console :) Ruby 2.3 x64, Windows 10 x64. Maybe the operating system causes the problem?

Comment: Second loop it's faster in my computer, MacBook Pro i7 SSD. with El Capitan

Comment: First taking 0.900022 sec and second one taking 0.873427 time om machine

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce this as well on my Windows 7 (64 bit) using Ruby 2.1.5 but not on my Linux machine using the same version. The first script only takes 0.8 seconds as opposed to 3.8 for the second.

Comment: Ah, after placing the answer I noticed you actually use a 64-bit version of ruby and OS. Still, could you try to determine the max integer number using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/535763/1544012) on your particular ruby/win combination?

Comment: ``machine_bytes => 8``
``machine_bits => 64``
``machine_max_signed  => 9223372036854775807``
``machine_max_unsigned => 18446744073709551615`` on both Linux/Windows.

Comment: @BoraMa Here they are:
machine_bytes: 8
machine_bits: 64
machine_max_signed: 9223372036854775807
machine_max_unsigned: 18446744073709551615
FIXNUM_MAX: 1073741823
FIXNUM_MIN: -1073741824

Comment: @Hast then it means that while you have a 64-bit OS, the ruby itself still limits Fixnum numbers to 4 bytes (it is 8 bytes on my Linux system) and my answer is I believe actually correct. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example processes much larger numbers than the first one (as @Sergii K commented above). It is possible that the second sample code reaches the maximum Fixnum limit on your system. On a 32-bit system, the [maximum signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/535763/1544012) is `2**(32-1) - 1 = 2147483647` which is much less than the maximum product `j * prev` in the second example (as opposed to max products in the first example). In a situation like this ruby has to convert the [Fixnums](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html) to [Bignums](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Bignum.html) internally which is why the second sample code may be slower than the first one.

On a 64-bit system I would expect both samples to run approximately the same time because the biggest integers will never reach the Fixnum limit. That is why perhaps most other commenters did not see a big difference in the timings.

**Update**: if the max Fixnum number is only 1073741823, as commented by the OP above, then it must mean that while the OS itself is 64-bits and perhaps the installed ruby is also a 64-bit ruby, it still uses only 4 bytes to store Fixnum numbers (instead of 8 in truly 64-bit rubies). The max integer value is much less then needed in the second example so it indeed has to convert the higher numbers to Bignums and that is where the slowness of the second sample comes from.

You can check this yourself if you compare:

```
(2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1).class      # => Fixnum vs:
(2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1 + 1).class  # => should be Bignum
```