# Can You Count Infinitely in Ruby Using a Case Statement?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to calculate what happens if the total score averages out above 100. I'm currently using a case statement to output the different scores. Would be the optimal solution to express the range above 100, allowing us to output 'A+++'.

```
def get_grade(score_1, score_2, score_3)
  total = (score_1 + score_2 + score_3)/3

  case total
  # What if the score is above 100? 
  # I want it to express 'A+++'
  when 90..100 then 'A'
  when 80..89 then 'B'
  when 70..79 then 'C'
  when 60..69 then 'D'
  else             'F'
  end
end

p get_grade(91, 97, 93) # => 'A'
p get_grade(52, 57, 51) # => 'D'
p get_grade(105, 106, 107) # => 'A++'
```

Comment: I prefer @Nic's solution, but you could add either of the following lines to the case statement: `when 101..Float::INFINITY then 'A+++'` or `when 101..total then 'A+++'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a typical  case for the `else` clause. Why not rework your `case` statement to look like this, assuming each score argument is non-negative:

```
case total
  when 90..100 then 'A'
  when 80..89 then 'B'
  when 70..79 then 'C'
  when 60..69 then 'D'
  when 0..59 then 'F'
  else 'A+++'
end
```

Comment: I thought about that for sure; I just didn't know if there was another way to do so using INFINITY or anything else? Thanks!

Comment: You could, but Ruby does not define a constant like `Fixnum::MAX`. Figuring out the actual value would be a little too involved, like [here](https://gist.github.com/pithyless/9738125) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/736313/2116518). Therefore it's probably better to stick to a simple solution.

Comment: @NicNilov what about user passes one or more negative numbers as argument (which makes total < 0)?

Answer (score 4):

You may combine methods and use comparisons

```
...
else
    if total > 100
        "A+++"
    else
         "F"
    end
end
```

If you want to play a little, you could change the case statement to:

```
(total > 100) ? "A+++" : "FFFFFFDCBAA"[(total/10).to_i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a proc to the case to allow you to use an expression like `> 100`

```
def get_grade(score_1, score_2, score_3)
  total = (score_1 + score_2 + score_3)/3

  case total
  # What if the score is above 100? 
  # I want it to express 'A+++'
  when 90..100 then 'A'
  when 80..89 then 'B'
  when 70..79 then 'C'
  when 60..69 then 'D'
  when ->(n) { n > 100 } then 'A+++'
  else 'F'
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a nice use of lambda but it kinda duplicates the semantics of the `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty solution using infinity:

first mentioned by [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646583/can-you-count-infinitely-in-ruby-using-a-case-statement/47414124#comment64679805_38646583)

```
case total
  when 101..Float::INFINITY then 'A+++'
  when 90..100 then 'A'
  when 80..89 then 'B'
  when 70..79 then 'C'
  when 60..69 then 'D'
  else 'F'
end
```