# Max and Min value of Fixnum and Bignum in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering the range of Fixnum and Bignum.
In Float, I can get the range of Float with Float::MAX and Float::MIN.
There are not analogous constants in Fixnum and Bignum.
What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535721/ruby-max-integer

Comment: TLDR there is no Max int in ruby

Comment: Not convinced? `(2**100_000).to_s.size #=> 30103 `.

Comment: I got `warning: in a**b, b may be too big` warning when I tried to print the `2**100000000` in the pry console. Ruby version was `2.3.8p459`. It still produces a result but it's `Infinity`.

Comment: The smallest power of 10 that is not expressible with Bignum in Ruby is `10**9942067`. I verified it by myself.

Comment: EDIT: It may differ from OS to OS: In Windows, for example, it is `10**9942058`.

Answer (score 8):

Forget [`Fixnum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html) and [`Bignum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Bignum.html). They are private internal implementation details. They are optimizations. You should ignore them. The only class you should be concerned about is [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html).

The [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579) only specifies the `Integer` class. It allows for implementation-specific subclasses, but it doesn't specify them.

`Fixnum`s are an optimization that should be internal to the implementation and should never have been exposed to the programmer. Think about *flonum*s in YARV. Did you even notice [*flonum*s were introduced in YARV 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6763)? All they do is make certain [`Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html)s faster. But you never see them. Which is as it should be.

And in fact, [YARV 2.4 removes `Fixnum` and `Bignum` and will only have `Integer`s in the future](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12005). `Fixnum` and `Bignum` will stay around for a while as aliases for `Integer`, for backwards-compatibility reasons, but the classes themselves will be gone.

In Ruby, `Integer`s don't have a maximum or minimum value; they are arbitrary-size integers. Therefore, there aren't any such constants.

The size limit for `Fixnum`s (if they exist at all) depends on the platform and implementation. On JRuby, `Fixnum`s are always 64-bit, on YARV, they are 63-bit on 64-bit platforms and 31-bit on 32-bit platforms. On Opal, `Integer`s are implemented as ECMAScript `Number`s (which are actually IEEE754 floats and thus are only accurate for 53-bits), and [I don't think they even have `Fixnum`s or `Bignum`s](https://github.com/opal/opal/pull/1025).