# Using a number as default index

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

I have an array of a reasonable size,

```
a = ("a".."z").to_a
```

and I want to use a certain default number that would (practically) always return `nil` when used to call a value as an index.

```
a[some_default_index] # => nil
```

For a fixed `a`, I can set a fixed number equal to or larger than `a`'s size as the default number, but `a` varies.

I tried `Float::NAN` and `Float::Infinity`, which did not work as I intended.

```
a[Float::NAN] # => out of range error
a[Float::Infinity] # => out of range error
```

What number can I use as an index?

Comment: Why can't you just use `a[a.size]`?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
max_index = 2**30 - 1
a[max_index] # => nil
```

The error message gives the hint `` RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long' ``

That is, the index must fit into `long` value in the underlying machine-level representation of Ruby. On a 32-bit system that would be `2**31 - 1` and `2**63 - 1` on a 64-bit system.

However, these values are to big to be represented as a `Fixnum` in Ruby so if you want to take advantage of the immediate speedup of fixnums best use their maximum value instead. Ruby uses tag pointers to represent `Fixnum` integers, hence they are one bit smaller that native integers and thus  `2**30 - 1` for a 32-bit system and `2**62 - 1` for a 64-bit system.

Comment: That creates a `Bignum` on 32-bit system. Ruby uses tag pointers hence integers are one bit smaller.

Answer (score 1):

## Largest correct index

Here's an adapted version of @AndrewGrimm's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539432/6419007) :

```
a = ("a".."z").to_a

start = Time.now
largest_correct_index = 1
smallest_incorrect_index = nil

until smallest_incorrect_index == largest_correct_index + 1
  if smallest_incorrect_index.nil?
    next_number_to_try = largest_correct_index * 1000
  else
    next_number_to_try = (smallest_incorrect_index + largest_correct_index) / 2 # Geometric mean would be more efficient, but more risky
  end

  if next_number_to_try <= largest_correct_index ||
       smallest_incorrect_index && next_number_to_try >= smallest_incorrect_index
    raise "Can't happen case"
  end

  begin
    a[next_number_to_try]
    largest_correct_index = next_number_to_try
  rescue RangeError
    smallest_incorrect_index = next_number_to_try
  end
end

finish = Time.now
puts "The largest correct index is #{largest_correct_index}"
puts "The smallest incorrect index is #{smallest_incorrect_index}"
puts "Calculation took #{finish - start} seconds"
```

On 32-bit Ruby, it returned `2**31-1`:

```
The largest correct index is 2147483647
The smallest incorrect index is 2147483648
Calculation took 0.0 seconds
```

On 64-bit Ruby and JRuby, it returned `2**63-1`:

```
The largest correct index is 9223372036854775807
The smallest incorrect index is 9223372036854775808
Calculation took 0.000250378 seconds
```

So it looks like @akuhn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41818619/6419007) should be good enough in most cases.

## Alternative

Depending on your needs, you could also use a hash :

```
a = ('a'..'z').to_a
# ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

h = ('a'..'z').map.with_index { |l, i| [i, l] }.to_h
# {0=>"a", 1=>"b", 2=>"c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e", 5=>"f", 6=>"g", 7=>"h", 8=>"i", 9=>"j", 10=>"k", 11=>"l", 12=>"m", 13=>"n", 14=>"o", 15=>"p", 16=>"q", 17=>"r", 18=>"s", 19=>"t", 20=>"u", 21=>"v", 22=>"w", 23=>"x", 24=>"y", 25=>"z"}

require 'fruity'

compare do
  _array { a[rand(26)] }
  _hash  { h[rand(26)] }
end
```

It doesn't seem to impact performances negatively :

```
Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_array is similar to _hash
```

All those :

```
h[-1]
h[:default]
h[Float::INFINITY]
h[2**1024-1]
```

would return `nil`.

Comment: +1 for scientific experiment. Guess you could have used `Range#bsearch`, or is there a reason that would fail?

Comment: Seem to work `(0..1000**1000).bsearch { |x| [][x] && false rescue true }`

Comment: Excellent comment. I just copy-pasted the code from the linked answer and adapted it to this question.